# JavaScript setTimeout setInterval

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I am writing some code for a website and I want to create a 165px x 2px line that shows up and then disappears and continues to do that to infinity. I have wrote this code in JavaScript:

```
function sivapokretna() {
        document.getElementById("pokretnasiva").style.width= "165px";
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('pokretnasiva').style.width= '0px';", 4000);
}

function sivo() {
    setInterval(sivapokretna(), 8000);
}
```

As you can see, in the first function I change the size of the div element from 0 to 165 and then after delay I turn it back to 0. For some reason, it is only done once although I used setInterval in the second function. Not to be confused, I have done changing with CSS3 3 seconds transition. Here is the CSS part of the code of the element that is changing.

```
#pokretnasiva {
    width: 0px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ff0000;
    transition: width 3s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the function to `setInterval`. You are invoking the function so you're actually passing its *return value* (which is `undefined` since there is no explicit `return` statement).

You need to remove the invoking parentheses:

```
setInterval(sivapokretna, 8000);
//                     ^--- No invoking parentheses here!
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But now there is 8s delay at the beginning... How can I make it start changing right away?

Comment: @user1687538 - Just call `sivapokretna` before calling `setInterval`. For example: `sivapokretna(); setInterval(sivapokretna, 8000);`

Answer (score 1):

You are **calling** the function, running immediately, and then telling `setInterval` to run `undefined` (the return value of the function) over and over.

You need to *pass the function*, not **call** the function and pass its return value.

Remove the `()`.

```
setInterval(sivapokretna, 8000)
```